# Require Specific Element Values depending on Values of Parent's Sibling's Children

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I am trying to work out the schema for requiring that the values of instances of an element are sequential without any gaps (although the order does not matter).

**Valid:**

```
<Racks>
  <Rack>
    <RackNumber>1</RackNumber>
  </Rack>
  <Rack>
    <RackNumber>2</RackNumber>
  </Rack>
  <Rack>
    <RackNumber>3</RackNumber>
  </Rack>
</Racks>
```

**Valid:**

```
<Racks>
  <Rack>
    <RackNumber>2</RackNumber>
  </Rack>
  <Rack>
    <RackNumber>3</RackNumber>
  </Rack>
  <Rack>
    <RackNumber>1</RackNumber>
  </Rack>
</Racks>
```

**Not Valid:**

```
<Racks>
  <Rack>
    <RackNumber>1</RackNumber>
  </Rack>
  <Rack>
    <RackNumber>3</RackNumber>
  </Rack>
</Racks>
```

Is enforcing this possible with XSD 1.0? If so, then can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not convenient way to do this in XSD 1.0.  In XSD 1.1 you could use assertions (on the parent `Racks` element) to enforce the constraint.  But if it were me, I'd change the XML to entail less redundancy and less interdependency between adjacent elements.

Comment: Bases on the xml i posted i can see why you suggest simplifying the schema. In reality Rack elements are parents to several generations of child nodes descrbing what's in each rack. I control the source code for the applications that create and use the xml so i can always enfotce this in my application code.